# ¿Cómo hacer un salto de linea dentro de un formulario de texto en `bootstrap`?

Tags: bootstrap, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario con bootstrap. El contenido de todos los items del formulario son `strings` introducidos manualmente por el usuario.
El contenido se agrega a un archivo de texto plano que se descarga en el equipo del usuario.

La pregunta es ¿cómo puedo admitir saltos de linea con la tecla <kbd>enter</kbd>?.

De manera que cuando el usuario en introduzca texto en un campo del formulario y pulse <kbd>enter</kbd> en lugar de saltar al siguiente campo, pueda seguir escribiendo mas texto en una nueva línea dentro del mismo campo.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un ejemplo (con código) del formulario?

Comment: Esto puede dar una idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481025/the-val-of-a-textarea-doesnt-take-new-lines-into-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin saber más detalles acerca de tu código, aplicación y lenguaje de backend yo creo que tienes que usar campos de tipo **`textarea`**, ya que estos admiten saltos de línea, al contrario que los inputs de tipo `text`, que solamente contienen una línea de texto.

Existen formas de insertar saltos de línea en los inputs de texto, pero son soluciones artificiosas que requieren que el usuario introduzca caracteres especiales u "oscuros trucos" con javascript, lo cual no recomiendo.

Comment: Gracias. Efetivamente si hago el campo del formulario                        <textarea class="form-control" id="resumen" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea> el usuario puede hacer salto de linea pulsando enter, pero no así en el string obtenido. Lo leo por medio de      texto = $('#idcampo').val()+'\r\n' pero no recoge el salto de linea del usuario

Answer (score 0):

En las ocasiones que es necesario mostrar los espacios en blanco de un texto y  **los saltos de linea**  introducidos por el usuario.

Se puede utilizar la etiqueta `<pre>`, que muestra el texto tal y como se ha escrito por el usuario, incluyendo los saltos de linea que las otras etiquetas como `< p>` obvian a menos que introduzcas un `< br>` en medio.

con la etiqueta `<b>< pre></b>` muestras todo eso.

Ejemplo:

```
< pre>{ tu.variable }< /pr>
```

mira mas informacion acerca de eso aqui https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/xhtml/capitulo-3/espacios-en-blanco-y-nuevas-lineas